# AngularJS - Generating an array with a for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple image gallery where each file is sequentially numbered from 001 to 235 with a .jpg extention.

How can I loop through 001 to 235 without having to repeat my array 235 times?

AngularJS code:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('gallery', [ ]);

app.controller('controllerGallery', function(){
    this.images = photos;
});

var photos = [
    {
        thumb:  '001'
    },
    {
        thumb:  '002'
    },
    {
        thumb:  '003'
    },
];
})();
```

HTML code:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="gallery">

<body ng-controller="controllerGallery as gallery">

<div class="container">
    <div class="thumb" ng-repeat="image in gallery.images">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img ng-src="/img/thumbs/{{image.thumb}}.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rf6p7quk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the array automatically:

```
var photos = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 235; i++) {
    photos.push({ thumb: padLeft(i, 3) });
}

// utility function
function padLeft (num, length) {
    num = num.toString();
    while (num.length < length) {
        num = '0' + num;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.